# IPHONE SQLite DBManager wrapper tutorial

Tags: ios4, fmdb

I'm new to database usage and i want a good tutorial to learn about fmdb wrapper for sqlite. Apparently this is an easier way than using the core data. Please Guide

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this as a good basic fmdb tutorial: [FMDB Tutorial](http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/11/04/simple-sqlite-database-interaction-using-fmdb/)

Comment: ok.. this i saw... n tried.. now i got to know how to extract data from database.. but how to insert, delete , edit , update , move up , move down in runtime?? for tat im not finding any information...

Comment: The tutorial got a paragraph titled 'Inserting And Deleting Data' . Follow that. If you know sqlite commands well, then just pass that as a string. Study the fmdb user guide, .m and .h files to grab the keywords.